# how can i create custom field on the right side of the fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

how can i create custom field on the right side of the fullcalendar?

Please see the below picture, "sum" field.

[image]

Comment: for that you would probably need a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js). But it is a lot of potentially complicated work to integrate and maintain such a thing (even if you start by cloning the code of one of the built-in views). Consider first how essential your proposed feature really is.

Comment: I'll have to chew it over. Thank you so much.